# ag-grid getColumnState never return groups

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am trying to get the column data from ag-grid's `gridColumnApi` and render some custom stuff myself. However the function `getColumnState` or even `getColumnGroupState` never return the group info...

`getColumnGroupState` only return null, and `gridColumnState` only return all the columns including the children under each group... but never including the groups.

The thing is that, the table itself displayed fine, I could see the grouping in the header, however accessing the column group data via the API doesn't seems to be accessible...

I drilled down into the ag-grid's framework, and those data are there, but under something call `gridBalancedTree...`

Does anyone know how to read all the columns including the groups for ag-grid?

Comment: Do you still have this issue?  Am facing the same with getColumnGroupState always returning empty array

Comment: I had to implement my workaround and keep track of the state on my own... but given that I am not the only one, I would think this is a bug, I was using v20, and hopefully they fix it in the newer versions. I cannot upgrade yet as v21+ have breaking changes.